# Detecting changes in iCal files

Tags: icalendar, rfc2445, rfc5545

I'm writing a little desktop application that plugs into Google Calendar (or other iCal-powered services) and displays event reminders. It automatically redownloads the iCal file every so often. If the file checksum has changed, I throw out the current appointment cache and reparse the calendar.

The thing is, this doesn't work with Google Calendar files. Upon further inspection, it came to my attention that the `DTSTAMP:` [property](http://www.kanzaki.com/docs/ical/dtstamp.html) on all events changed every time I redownloaded the iCal file associated with a certain calendar. So a standard checksum may not be the way to go here. There are two main solutions I'm considering.

- Calculating the checksum based on the original file with the `DTSTAMP:` lines thrown out. *(dirty)*
- Implementing a full calendar diff algorithm that detects which sections of the calendar are new, which have been thrown out, which have changed, etc. *(expensive)*

I don't know if the iCal format has any other quirks I haven't discovered yet, so I don't know if method 1 will solve my problem. Limited tests seem to indicate that it does. On the other hand, method 2 seems unnecessarily costly in terms of CPU power.

What would you suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if google calendar follows 100% of rfc5545 but there should be a sequence number which "defines the revision sequence number of the calendar component within a sequence of revisions."

Comment: This would be useful if I were to implement a diff algorithm [(context)](http://www.kanzaki.com/docs/ical/sequence.html). I can verify that Google's ICS files have this field, but I don't know if they're applying it consistently.